# Liquibase: How to rollback specific changeset without rolling back all subsequent changesets

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms, liquibase

Is it possible in Liquibase to rollback some specific changeset only without rolling back all subsequent changesets?

For example, I have following changesets structure:

```
initial -> changeset1 (CREATE TABLE A) -> changeset2 (CREATE TABLE B)
```

I know that both changesets are completelly independent and can be rolled back in any order. Now I want to rollback `changeset1` to have following structure:

```
initial -> changeset2 (CREATE TABLE B)
```

Reason why I want to do this is because I have a big system and lot of features developed in parallel. Features have independent changesets. Features deployed in parallel so their changesets can be applied to database in any order. I want to have ability to rollback changesets of one feature only without touching changes of other features.

Comment: I'm having this very same issue right now.  I was hoping somebody had answered this for you. unfortunately... looks like it's not possible.  Did you ever figure this out?